# Update plist with json data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, plist

I am saving json content in plist file.

```
//Fetch json
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//Get json in dictionary format
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"dict: %@",dict);

//Get plist path
NSString *errorDesc;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.plist"];
NSLog(@"plistPath : %@",plistPath);

//Save data from json to plist
NSString *error;
data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dict
                                                  format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                        errorDescription:&error];
if(data) {
    if ([data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"Data successfully saved.");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Did not managed to save NSData.");
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"%@",errorDesc);
}
```

And it is working perfectly.

Now suppose, Someone has added a new item in json. Then how to append only new item into plist.

PS: Here, i dont want to rewrite entire plist. I just want to check whether json is updated or not. If json is updated then I want to update the plist by appending only new item.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistContent = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
[plistContent setObject:value forKey:key];
[plistContent writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your .plist is initially an exact copy of the JSON data. Are there other bits of code that modify the .plist? If not, why would you want to write the changes only? This is highly complicated code, easy to get wrong, and will take lots of time. Writing all the JSON data to the plist is by far the easiest way to do this.

*If* you have other bits of code that modify the .plist, then you have to keep track of the JSON data as well, because otherwise you can't know whether and how it has been modified. Good luck.